# Using zoom on a specific div only

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming

We have a seatplan that when on mobiles would be handy to have a zoom function on the setaplan only. At the moment when you zoom in using pinch on an Andoid mobile it will zoom in, but you have to pinch out fully to maintain the responsive look of the page.

Here is an example of the #seats div I wish to zoom in on
https://jsfiddle.net/ohaumyxj/

Is this something that can be achieved with plain CSS or does jQuery come into the mix here? I am looking for the type of thing you get with Google Maps on a contact page of a site or perhaps a bit better with a tap zoom function.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#bmessage {
  padding: 1px 3px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #ddf;
  color: #080;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#seats:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding: 50%;
}
#seats {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(https://s21.postimg.org/qd8mqgh07/seatplan11.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
#seats div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.5%;
  height: 1.5%;
}
#seats .green {
  background: url('https://s12.postimg.org/93ugmrvb1/seatg.gif') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="theatre">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="bmessage">Select the seats that you need.</div>
    <div id="seats">
      <div class="avail std green" si="332" title="Y1" style="top: 8.7%; left: 10.2%; border: none; margin: 3px 1px;"></div>
      <div class="avail std green" si="333" title="Y2" style="top:8.7%; left:13%;"></div>
      <div class="avail std green" si="334" title="Y3" style="top:8.7%; left:16.2%;"></div>
      <div class="avail std green" si="335" title="Y4" style="top: 8.7%; left: 18.8%; border: none; margin: 3px 1px;"></div>
      <div class="avail std green" si="336" title="Y5" style="top: 8.7%; left: 21.5%; border: none; margin: 3px 1px;"></div>
      <div class="avail std green" si="337" title="Y6" style="top:8.7%; left:24.2%;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/    .It's a jQuery library

Comment: Thanks Puru, I like the look of this. The only potential issue with this is the users click on the seats to book them. So that click on a seat would result in a zoom

Comment: Struggling to get Zoomooz working with this div structure, perhaps the "Zooming inside a container" is the solution I require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/mfqgkytq/#&togetherjs=FjwCqtEjqy)

HTML

```
<div id="theatre" class="zoomViewport">
        <div class="container zoomContainer">
            <div id="bmessage">Select the seats that you need.</div>
            <div id="seats" class="zoomTarget">
                <div class="avail std green" si="332" title="Y1" style="top: 8.7%; left: 10.2%; border: none; margin: 3px 1px;"></div>
                <div class="avail std green" si="333" title="Y2" style="top:8.7%; left:13%;"></div>
                <div class="avail std green" si="334" title="Y3" style="top:8.7%; left:16.2%;"></div>
                <div class="avail std green" si="335" title="Y4" style="top: 8.7%; left: 18.8%; border: none; margin: 3px 1px;"></div>
                <div class="avail std green" si="336" title="Y5" style="top: 8.7%; left: 21.5%; border: none; margin: 3px 1px;"></div>
                <div class="avail std green" si="337" title="Y6" style="top:8.7%; left:24.2%;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#seats").click(function (evt) {
                $(this).zoomTo({ targetsize: 0.75, duration: 600 });
                evt.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
```

Comment: If you put that fiddle to mobile size and tap to zoom in, it doesn't seem to zoom into the seatplan. I actually just moves the div for me with no zoom present as far as I can see

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
var zoomable = document.getElementById('seats'),
    zX = 1;
window.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
    var dir;
    if (!e.ctrlKey) {
        return;
    }
    dir = (e.deltaY > 0) ? 0.1 : -0.1;
    zX += dir;
    zoomable.style.transform = 'scale(' + zX + ')';
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
});
```